# extracting MPEG-7 low-level audio descriptors using essentia

Tags: audio, feature-extraction

According to https://www.ntnu.edu/documents/1001201110/1266017954/DAFx-15_submission_43_v2.pdf, the audio processing toolbox *Essentia* includes the 100% of MPEG-7 low-level audio descriptors. However I have been trying to use it to extract them from a .wav file, and I can't find their names in *Essentia*'s documentation.

My question is: Does *Essentia* actually include those descriptors out of the box (I mean, as a function, as it does with the MFCCs for instance), but maybe with different names than the originals? Or is it that it only includes "general tools" (as Spectrum extractors) to help with the actual extraction of those features?

In either case, could someone please explain here (or refer to a place where it is explained) how to get the seventeen MPEG-7 low-level descriptors **USING *ESSENTIA***?

Comment: Indeed, take a look [here](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/algorithms_reference.html).

Comment: I did, and they aren't mentioned anywhere in the page

Comment: Really? Which ones are missing?

Comment: audio waveform, audio spectrum envelope, audio spectrum centroid, audio spectrum spread, audio spectrum flatness... And those are just the ones I have had to implement by myself so far.

Comment: I know there are functions similar to those, but the thing is their results are not in the log-frequency bands specified in the MPEG-7 standard. So for that purpose they can't be directly employed.

Comment: @jojek However if you know how to EASILY use Essentia to produce the results in the log-frequency bands, or it is specified somewhere else, please tell me (especially for the audio spectrum flatness which turned out to be pretty difficult to implement by the MPEG-7 specifications)

Comment: Well actually once you get the audio spectrum envelope (ASE), you can get the centroid and the spread from it... But the point here is: even if you just need the spectrum centroid you need to implement the ASE first

Comment: All of these metrics can be calculated using the existing transforms. What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using python. Could you please explain me how to do it in the shortest way?

Comment: @jojek I'm still waiting for those transforms you mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Essentia documentation, the MPEG-7 isn't listed directly as a function from where you can extract features.

The audio descriptors in the MPEG-7 standard are listed [here](http://mpeg7.org/audio-descriptors/). I think you will have to take use various functions to create your own feature vector. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the same... The reason why I made this question is because according to the mentioned paper, Essentia does contain the 100% of MPEG-7 audio low-level descriptors, which to me seems to be inaccurate.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the paper but maybe it does but they don't have one function for all the descriptors. You may have to use multiple feature extraction functions.

Comment: Of course I didn't expect to get the 17 descriptors from a single function. My point is there are several descriptors which aren't included (IN ANY POSSIBLE WAY) into the Essentia library